Select polygons that are within a selected bounding box for a kontur population data
I have a data from https://data.humdata.org/dataset/kontur-population-dataset? and I would like to select the polygons that are within a bounding box. For instance I define bounding box as follows (a bounding box around Berlin):
bounding_box = {
    "min_lon": 12.927785560520098,
    "max_lon": 13.94903874307725,
    "min_lat": 52.284843473119714,
    "max_lat": 52.77168805093944
} 

I tried to do it in a following way but it returns an empty file:
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import box
data = gpd.read_file('C:/Users/Julian/Downloads/kontur_population.gpkg/kontur_population.gpkg')
bounding_box = {
    "min_lon": 12.927785560520098,
    "max_lon": 13.94903874307725,
    "min_lat": 52.284843473119714,
    "max_lat": 52.77168805093944
}
min_lon = bounding_box["min_lon"]
max_lon = bounding_box["max_lon"]
min_lat = bounding_box["min_lat"]
max_lat = bounding_box["max_lat"]

bbox = box(min_lon, min_lat, max_lon, max_lat)
clipped_data = data[data.geometry.within(bbox)]
clipped_data.to_file('C:/Users/Julian/Downloads/kontur_population.gpkg/kontur_population.gpkg', driver="GPKG")

I would be grateful for any help in that matter !

There were 2 errors is your script:

the data is in crs 3857 (WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator), not in 4326 (standard WGS 84), and your bounding box should be in the same projection as the data
your pandas dataframe filter missed .loc[...]

In addition, I speeded up the script this way:

I added a bbox filter in the read_file call already. This will filter the data already roughly using the spatial index present in the .gpkg file, speading up the reading a lot.
I added engine="pyogrio" for reading and writing. In general, the "pyogrio" engine is a lot faster that the default one. In the next version of geopandas, this will become the default.

Corrected script:
from pathlib import Path
import geopandas as gpd
from pyproj import Transformer
from shapely.geometry import box, Point
from shapely.ops import transform

bounding_box = {
    "min_lon": 12.927785560520098,
    "max_lon": 13.94903874307725,
    "min_lat": 52.284843473119714,
    "max_lat": 52.77168805093944,
}

min_lon = bounding_box["min_lon"]
max_lon = bounding_box["max_lon"]
min_lat = bounding_box["min_lat"]
max_lat = bounding_box["max_lat"]

# Convert bbox to crs of data: epsg:3857
transformer = Transformer.from_crs(4326, 3857)
min_3857 = transform(transformer.transform, Point(min_lat, min_lon))
max_3857 = transform(transformer.transform, Point(max_lat, max_lon))

# dir = Path("C:/Temp/test_population")
dir = Path("C:/Users/Julian/Downloads/kontur_population.gpkg")
data = gpd.read_file(
    dir / "kontur_population_20231101.gpkg",
    bbox=(min_3857.x, min_3857.y, max_3857.x, max_3857.y),
    engine="pyogrio",
)

bbox = box(min_3857.x, min_3857.y, max_3857.x, max_3857.y)
clipped_data = data.loc[data.geometry.within(bbox)]
clipped_data.to_file(
    dir / "kontur_population_within.gpkg",
    driver="GPKG",
    engine="pyogrio",
)

